# Maven : Not able to autowire from service module to controller module

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Here is my project structure

[image]

parent is the parent project of client, controller, service and repository.

now I want to add the dependency of service in controller, so added the same like in controller pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.freelancing.fullstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In controller project, I have a MainController class.

```
@RestController
public class MainController
{
    @Autowired
    ServiceClass sc;

    @GetMapping("test")
    public void testing()
    {
        sc.callService();
    }
}
```

Now while running the controller project as springboot application, I am facing below error:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController' defined in file [E:\parent\controller\target\classes\org\controller\MainController.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.controller.MainController] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@574aa597]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.controller.ControllerClass.main(ControllerClass.java:11) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.controller.MainController] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@574aa597]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:734) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:666) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:382) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:569) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/service/ServiceClass;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:729) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.service.ServiceClass
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:144) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        ... 30 common frames omitted

seems like ServiceClass bean is not available at runtime.
```

After adding componentscan annotation

```
facing this issue.

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]  [INFO] ----------------<
> com.freelancing.fullstack:controller >---------------- [INFO] Building
> controller 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar
> ]--------------------------------- [INFO]  [INFO] >>>
> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) >
> test-compile @ controller >>> [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:copy-resources (copy-resources) @
> controller --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered
> resources. [INFO] Copying 22 resources [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @
> controller --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered
> resources. [INFO] Copying 1 resource [INFO] Copying 0 resource [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @
> controller --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
> [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources
> (default-testResources) @ controller --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding
> to copy filtered resources. [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory
> E:\parent\controller\src\test\resources [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @
> controller --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
> [INFO]  [INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run
> (default-cli) < test-compile @ controller <<< [INFO]  [INFO]  [INFO]
> --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ controller --- [INFO] Attaching agents: []
> 
>   .   ____          _            __ _ _  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __
> _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / / 
> =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)
> 
> 2019-12-27 10:51:29.859  INFO 6184 --- [  restartedMain]
> org.controller.ControllerClass           : Starting ControllerClass on
> DESKTOP-551C51M with PID 6184 (E:\parent\controller\target\classes
> started by sparsh in E:\parent\controller) 2019-12-27 10:51:29.864 
> INFO 6184 --- [  restartedMain] org.controller.ControllerClass        
> : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
> 2019-12-27 10:51:29.927  INFO 6184 --- [  restartedMain]
> .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults
> active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
> 2019-12-27 10:51:29.927  INFO 6184 --- [  restartedMain]
> .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related
> logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
> 2019-12-27 10:51:31.375  INFO 6184 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with
> port(s): 9091 (http) 2019-12-27 10:51:31.384  INFO 6184 --- [ 
> restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting
> service [Tomcat] 2019-12-27 10:51:31.384  INFO 6184 --- [ 
> restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting
> Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29] 2019-12-27 10:51:31.456  INFO
> 6184 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :
> Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext 2019-12-27
> 10:51:31.457  INFO 6184 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext:
> initialization completed in 1529 ms 2019-12-27 10:51:31.753  INFO 6184
> --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor' 2019-12-27
> 10:51:31.805  INFO 6184 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class
> path resource [resources/index.html] 2019-12-27 10:51:31.944  WARN
> 6184 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       :
> Unable to start LiveReload server 2019-12-27 10:51:31.950  INFO 6184
> --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator' 2019-12-27
> 10:51:32.009  INFO 6184 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
> 2019-12-27 10:51:32.019  INFO 6184 --- [  restartedMain]
> ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
> 
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-12-27 10:51:32.027
> ERROR 6184 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
> 
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> ***************************
> 
> Description:
> 
> Web server failed to start. Port 9091 was already in use.
> 
> Action:
> 
> Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 9091 or
> configure this application to listen on another port.
> 
> 2019-12-27 10:51:32.029  INFO 6184 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down
> ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor' [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 7.045 s [INFO] Finished at:
> 2019-12-27T10:51:32+05:30 [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Autowiring of beans is not working in maven multi module project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732402/spring-boot-autowiring-of-beans-is-not-working-in-maven-multi-module-project)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the scope `provided` in your service dependency.Maven dependency scope `provided` is used during build and test the project. They are also required to run, but is not exported(because the expectation is that the dependency will be provided by the runtime, for instance, by servlet container or application server). Use it like :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.freelancing.fullstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In a springboot application, normally the base package is taken as the package level at which the Main application is present. Since you have a multi-module project , it is possible that your other packages are not getting scanned for bean creation. So , try using the following configuration like, to specify the base package to spring for class path scanning for the auto configuration:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.yourBasePackage"})
```

Comment: thanks, for your reply, although after adding this build is successful but for any random port , port is already used. adding the error message above it it can help you

Comment: @sparsh610 I have updated my answer.Please try the renewed answer.

Comment: that bean not found issue got resolved but now it saying that port is already in use. and it is for every value, I changed it in application.properties as well

Comment: Use the command `netstat -ano ` to find all the pids that are using the port that you want the springboot application to use Kill all the pids and try again. Take care to stop any process that is using a particular port before starting your application in that.