# Bean/Component from another maven project not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection

I am new to the `Spring Boot` framework and currently trying to learn while working on a very large application. The application consists of many (`maven` based) `Spring Boot` projects and it has the following structure:

- `Project1`

  - `com.x.y.z`
  - `com.x.y.w`
- `Project2`

  - `com.x.y.a.b`
  - `com.x.y.a.c`
- `Project3`

  - `com.x.y.d.e`
  - `com.x.y.d.f`

All the projects output `jar` and are based on `com.x.y` packages. `Project1` contains the `main` function. There is a chance that any project is dependent on the other project (but not cyclic dependency since `maven` doesn't allow that). However, for the sake of example, assume `Project3` is dependent on `Project1`. Projects are `built with dependencies`.

**Question**

When I place any `@Component` *class* inside `Project1`, it finds them without any problem. However, when I place a `@Component` inside another project (`Project3` in our example) which is dependent on `Project1` (the main project) it fails to find it.

**Attempts to solve**

As suggested in the documentation and Google source, I have tried using `@ComponentScan("com.x.y")` in the `main` class as well, but it didn't work out.

Also, I have tried both solutions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732402/spring-boot-autowiring-of-beans-is-not-working-in-maven-multi-module-project) but they didn't work.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: how are you importing project 2 and 3, are sure you impored them properly?  If any of your bean needs another bean you should consider using @dependsOn annotation

Comment: Are you sure you put @ComponentScan("com.x.y") in all of your project's Configuration class?